# Draw on desktop (windows/ubuntu) using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, draw, desktop

I am doing a project in which I need to show lines on window. Also I want to move cursor along the line. I am looking forward to work in python.

How can I do this using python or other languages. Please help me

Comment: try "Turtle Graphics" in python.

Comment: @bhaskar4n turtle graphics is good, but that's not what iam looking for..

Answer (score 3):

i only just found this out and here you go.

```
import win32gui

def DRAW_LINE(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    hwnd=win32gui.WindowFromPoint((x1,y1))
    hdc=win32gui.GetDC(hwnd)
    x1c,y1c=win32gui.ScreenToClient(hwnd,(x1,y1))
    x2c,y2c=win32gui.ScreenToClient(hwnd,(x2,y2))
    win32gui.MoveToEx(hdc,x1c,y1c)
    win32gui.LineTo(hdc,x2c,y2c)
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc)

x1 = 640
y1 = 400
x2 = 840
y2 = 600

DRAW_LINE(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

as for moving your mouse underneath the lines i cant figure that out